# Проблема кодировок и оформления ( char* )

Tags: c++, qt

```
char* chRead;
QString isRead; //фаил загрузки примененных сейчас данных

QString D_path = "C:/WORK/";
QString D_format = "bin";
isRead = dlg.getOpenFileName(this,trUtf8("Открываем  ДАМПы RE"),D_path,trUtf8("DUMP(*.%1)").arg(D_format));

char* chRead2 = isRead.toAscii().data(); //перевод QString в char
```

отличается от

```
char* chRead;
chRead = "C:/Works/contr_glsso1/DUMP/SK0_20140305_192834_384.bin";
```

Результат разный. Не понимаю, в чем проблема - `qDebug`  выводит одно и тоже .

```
 chRead  C:/Works/contr_glsso1/DUMP/SK0_20140305_192834_384.bin
```

Comment: Я не очень понял, что вы хотите сделать, и в чём состоит проблема. Что вы выводите в `qDebug`? Почему вы присваиваете `chRead` какое-то значение руками? Попробуйте сделать минимальный работоспособный пример и следовать принципу: сделал - что хочу получить? - что получил

Answer (score 1):

Решил надо было правельно перевести в Char

```
char* value_name = new char[255];
char* sometext=isRead.toAscii().data();
value_name = sometext;
```

Вот код который добавил .

А вот в общей связке

```
QFileDialog dlg(this);
QString D_path = "C:/WORK/";
QString D_format = "bin";
isRead = dlg.getOpenFileName(this,trUtf8("Открываем  ДАМПы RE"),D_path,trUtf8("DUMP(*.%1)").arg(D_format));
if(isRead.isEmpty())
{
    return;
}
qDebug()<< isRead;
qDebug()<< "мы тут загружаем";

char* value_name = new char[255];
char* sometext=isRead.toAscii().data();
value_name = sometext;
```